# Create content database and re-add to TOP site collection

Tags: content-database

I have one Content DB which is of 250 GB. I want to create new DB and re-add to that particular TOP site collection.

This Web application has several content databases, each for its specific top site collection.

I want to create another content DB for that particular top site collection

Any suggestion?

Comment: Any suggestion please...

Answer (score 2):

In central admin go to Manage Content Databases [`http://CentralAdminURL/_admin/CNTDBADM.aspx`] and select your Web Application. Click "Add a content database" and fill in the form.

[image]

When done, you can move sites from one ContentDB to another by using the following PowerShell script

```
Move-SPSite http://servername/sites/sitename -DestinationDatabase NewContentDB
```

See [Move-SPSite](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607915.aspx) for more info.

For the record, SharePoint self-balance new sites to try to keep the number of Site Collection equal (by number) when new are created. That means a new ContenDB will get all new Site Collections until the numbers are equal with other Content Databases on the same Web Application.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply but it has only one Top site collection associated , which i can see from "manage content database" , so i am just wondering which one i can move . it might have subsite to it but don't access as of now .
I already created new content DB to this webaplication but as i said earlier there are many top site collection created inside it and each tope site is somehow linked to its individual Content DB, which i cant figure out..... So I want to add new content DB to one with bigger in size...

Comment: @Neeraj Then you're in for a bigger rework of your Web Application. You'd need to replace subsites with actual site collections, and that's a much bigger job. But it's doable.